# How can I remove a double string to have it only be the first word?

Tags: python, string, words

I have a string that is the same word twice, i.e. `"hihi"`. How can I remove the first `'hi'` so only the second occurrence exists?

Comment: `word[:len(word)/2]`?

Comment: that is used for integers right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string is always double, you can split it in the middle.

```
str_1 = "hihi"

print(str_1[len(str_1)//2:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the obvious, there's also regular expressions:

```
In [774]: re.sub(r'^(.*?)\1$', r'\1', "hihi")
Out[774]: 'hi'
```